# How to display color in two parts of a ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot line plots of several different series, where each series will be drawn with a different line width, and each belongs to one of several groups which will determine the color.

What I'm struggling to do is to create a legend which shows the group names and colors, as well as the individual series names and the width/color combination for each.

To give a minimal working example:

```
# Create data
names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")

df <- data.frame(
  name = rep(names, 3),
  group = rep(c(rep("X", 2), rep("Y", 2), rep("Z", 2)), 3),
  x = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 6), rep(3, 6)),
  y = c(runif(6, 0, 1), runif(6, 1, 2), runif(6, 2, 3)),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)


line.widths <- setName(runif(6, 0, 3), names)
group.colors <- setNames(c("#AA0000", "#00AA00", "#0000AA"), c("X", "Y", "Z"))
name.colors <- setNames(c(rep("#AA0000", 2), rep("#00AA00", 2), rep("#0000AA", 2)),
                        names)
```

And now the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Names and groups separately
ggplot(df, aes_string(x="x", y="y", group="name")) +
  geom_line(aes(size=name, color=group)) +
  scale_size_manual(values=line.widths) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=group.colors)
```

[image: Six lines, with three different colors and three different line sizes.]

My question is whether it's possible to add the group colors to the `name` portion of the legend, without losing the `group` portion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *incredibly* close (and thank you for the well researched and attempted question). You just need to add `override.aes` in the legend, like so:

```
ggplot(df, aes_string(x="x", y="y", group="name")) +
  geom_line(aes(size=name, color=group)) +
  scale_size_manual(values=line.widths) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=group.colors) +
  guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(col = name.colors)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling the answer used ``override.aes``, but I still haven't quite wrapped my head around ``guide``, ``guide_legend`` and ``override.aes``.